# EditorConfig for no-brace single-line if-statements

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I want to enforce a code style where single-line if{/else} are not allowed to have braces.

Example:

```cs
// No braces
if (cond)
    DoStuff();

// No braces with both if and else
if (cond)
    DoStuff();
else
    DoOtherStuff();

// Braces if one body is not single-line
if (cond)
{
    DoStuff();
}
else
{
    DoOtherStuff();
    ThenDoMoreStuff();
}
```

Is it possible to express this with EditorConfig?

I have tried reading through the EditorConfig documentation, sample .editorConfig files and the available formatting settings in Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: _"I want to enforce a code style where single-line if{/else} are not allowed to have braces."_ - second most infuriating thing I read today. Bad idea.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods Now I want to know what the first one was. Never seen braces cause a bug but I have seen many cases where lack of braces has.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Most infuriating thing today was my coworker telling me I had a bug in my PR (via Teams message posted yesterday after I had logged off, so it was the first thing in the morning ...). Fortunately, he was wrong, haha.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods It could be rephrased to "Company wants me to enforce...", but I did not think that info added value to the question.

Comment: Show "company" these comments :D But really: you need to push back. This _will_ decrease code quality and introduce bugs. And don't think "yeah but only with newbies". Nah-ah. But enough of that. It doesn't help you. I really hope someone can write that it's not possible using Editor-Config, though. It _really_ shouldn't.

Comment: _"I did not think that info added value to the question"_ - Well, it puts the question into perspective. I was just looking and I haven't found how that particular combination would be enforced, yet ... starting to think one might even need a static analyzer? Which doesn't make it less painful.

Answer (score 0):

My answer might not be super helpful directly (as I work with Java and IntelliJ) but maybe it points you in a direction:

In IntelliJ IDEA it is possible to export code style settings as a `.editorconfig` file. IDEA has a lot more options (especially language specific ones) so I can see plenty of configurations that will likely not work in other editors (e.g. they look like this: `ij_java_space_before_synchronized_left_brace = true`) but maybe you have a similar option to set code styling rules in your editor and subsequently export them.